# How can I show data using a modal when clicking a table row (using bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sort of a beginner on the whole web development thing and after researching a lot I still couldn't get this done. Any help is very much appreciated. I'm using latest rails version and bootstrap to make things prettier.

I have a page with a table which contains orders from a restaurant. If you click a row I want it to show the order details in a modal window using bootstrap. I have managed to open the modal via onclick+javascript function but it looks kinda messy and I still have no clue how to load the content div of the modal with the order info. Here's the code I have for this:

HTML:

```
<h1>Orders</h1>
<table class="table table-striped"
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @restaurant.orders.each do |order| %>
    <tr onclick="orderModal(<%= order.id  %>);">
      <td><%= order.id %></td>
      <td><%= order.customer_id %></td>
      <td><%= order.status %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="orderModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3>Order</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="orderDetails"class="modal-body"></div>
  
  <div id="orderItems" class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function orderModal(order_id){
    $('#orderModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One thing you can do is get rid of all those onclick attributes and do it the right way with bootstrap. You don't need to open them manually; you can specify the trigger and even subscribe to events before the modal opens so that you can do your operations and populate data in it.

I am just going to show as a static example which you can accommodate in your real world.

On each of your `<tr>`'s add a data attribute for `id` (i.e. `data-id`) with the corresponding id value and specify a `data-target`, which is a selector you specify, so that when clicked, bootstrap will select that element as modal dialog and show it. And then you need to add another attribute `data-toggle=modal` to make this a trigger for modal.

```
  <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="2" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
  <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="3" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
  </tr>
```

And now in the javascript just set up the modal just once and event listen to its events so you can do your work.

```
$(function(){
    $('#orderModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show:false,

    }).on('show', function(){ //subscribe to show method
          var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id'); //get the id from tr
        //make your ajax call populate items or what even you need
        $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow  + '</b>'))
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yF45N/)**

*Do not use inline click attributes any more. Use event bindings instead with vanilla js or using jquery.*

Alternative ways here:

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/kbmNu/)** or **[Demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/rHHmz/)**

Comment: @PSL. This is a very helpful example. Thank you. Instead of greying out the parent completely. How to change color of the row or add a border line color to the specific cell, indicating that the modal was invoked for the specific cell. So that the user knows modal refers to which row ? Not sure, if this already been addressed or needs a special Q. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @PSL, does not need to be specific cell. Highlighting the complete row in a way that user is aware that he is working with the modal of the specific row data. Let me know if it has to be a separate Q SO. I can work on creating one. Thanks

Comment: @PSL can i use this to look for data in database?inside modal?

Answer (score 10):

The solution from PSL will not work in Firefox. FF accepts event only as a formal parameter. So you have to find another way to identify the selected row.
My solution is something like this:

```
...
$('#mySelector')
  .on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var mid;


  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) 
    mid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  else
    mid = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');

...
```

Comment: thanks for the hint indeed the event show didn't fire

Comment: Thanks Paul, the firefox solution works for IE and Chrome too. I would suggest to go with that piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to ajax load the order information when click tr tag, and render the information html in $('#orderDetails') like this:

```
  $.get('the_get_order_info_url', { order_id: the_id_var }, function(data){
    $('#orderDetails').html(data);
  }, 'script')
```

Alternatively, you can add class for each td that contains the order info, and use jQuery method $('.class').html(html_string) to insert specific order info into your #orderDetails BEFORE you show the modal, like:

```
  <% @restaurant.orders.each do |order| %>
  <!-- you should add more class and id attr to help control the DOM -->
  <tr id="order_<%= order.id %>" onclick="orderModal(<%= order.id  %>);">
    <td class="order_id"><%= order.id %></td>
    <td class="customer_id"><%= order.customer_id %></td>
    <td class="status"><%= order.status %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

js:

```
function orderModal(order_id){
  var tr = $('#order_' + order_id);
  // get the current info in html table 
  var customer_id = tr.find('.customer_id');
  var status = tr.find('.status');

  // U should work on lines here:
  var info_to_insert = "order: " + order_id + ", customer: " + customer_id + " and status : " + status + ".";
  $('#orderDetails').html(info_to_insert);

  $('#orderModal').modal({
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: "static"
  });
};
```

That's it. But I strongly recommend you to learn sth about ajax on Rails. It's pretty cool and efficient.

Comment: I'll have to research a bit more to get the ajax request to work, but i get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: I just can't figure out how to do the ajax request. I tried (based on your 1st example) to put it in the 'on show' function but nothing happens and when i try to run it via browser console i get "Couldn't find Restaurant with id=get_order" like it's trying to use part of the url to set the @restaurant variable on the controller. Any thoughts?

Comment: see this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html