# Pass data to bootstrap model when model load using ajax

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a calender after I click on date I need to show all data related to that day in a bootstrap model.I used fullcalender as my calender. I manage to pass data to controller through ajax and get the result. But my problem is how to show this data inside specific div.

```
             dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'TodayCases',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { id: date.format() }
                }).done(function (result) {
                    $('#TodayCaseContainer').html(result);
                });
             }
```

if I use  `$('#Detail').modal('show');` it open the model without data how to combine that html respond to this model

My Model is

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Detail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="TodayCaseContainer">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995461/how-can-i-show-data-using-a-modal-when-clicking-a-table-row-using-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for your support. But it's not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the controller you could return a partial view with the content of the modal. The trick is to call a JavaScript function "onsuccess" from the ajax to toggle the modal. I used the built-in ajaxhelper from asp.net MVC 5 for a similar purpose.

**Markup Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        @Html.Action("_partialModal", "Home")
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modal Partial View:**

```
@Using Ajax.BeginForm("_partialModal", "Home", New AjaxOption With {
                                              .HttpMethode = "Post",
                                              .UpdateTargetID = "ModalCont",
                                              .OnSuccess = "toggleModal()"}, 
                                              New With {.id = "ModalCont"})
 ... Your modal content with Razor ...
End Using
```

**JavaScript to Toggle the modal**

```
    function toggleModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    }
```

Hope it helps.